# Fetch latest of 2 fields(columns) from multiple records by most efficient way

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to fetch the latest email and contact from multiple records. Each record has a date of creation. This row could or could not have an email/contact.

The table looks like this :

```
+--------------------------------------------+
ID | STUDENT_ID | EMAIL | CONTACT |DATE      |
1  |1           |null   |1001     |01-01-2020|
2  |1           |a@b.com|1002     |02-01-2020|
3  |1           |c@d.com|null     |03-01-2020|
4  |2           |y@z.com|1022     |01-01-2020|
+--------------------------------------------+
```

In this case expect output is for ID = 1 :

```
+-----------------------------+
 STUDENT_ID | EMAIL | CONTACT | 
1           |c@d.com|1002     |
+-----------------------------+
```

My query is

```
SELECT ( SELECT EMAIL 
         FROM TABLE_NAME  
         WHERE EMAIL != '' 
         AND STUDENT_ID = '1' 
        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 
        ) as EMAIL_L ,
       ( SELECT CONTACT 
         FROM TABLE_NAME  
         WHERE CONTACT != '' 
         AND STUDENT_ID = '1' 
         ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 
        ) as CONTACT_L 
FROM `TABLE_NAME` 
WHERE STUDENT_ID = '1' -- LIMIT 1 OR GROUP BY
```

Can I improve the query further ?

Comment: Hi Akash, this site doesn't like questions asking for opinions.

Comment: @RohitGupta asking for query improvement doesn't seem an opinion to me.

Comment: But 1001 is not the "latest contact"??

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for pointing out, I have fixed that in question. Kudos

Comment: Please check for more typos.  Perhaps `ORDER BY TABLE_NAME` should be `ORDER BY date DESC`.

Comment: hey @RickJames ty, I have improved the question. Hope it helps someone in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be using window_functions which require MySQL 8+.

In case of a null row get the next non null value.

Try,

```
with latest_non_null_val as (
SELECT  student_id, 
        date,
        COALESCE(email, LEAD (email) OVER (Partition by student_id ORDER BY date asc )) AS email,
        COALESCE(contact, LEAD (contact) OVER (Partition by student_id ORDER BY date desc )) AS contact,
        row_number() over (partition by student_id order by date desc ) latest_dt
FROM my_table
) select  student_id, email,contact,date
  from latest_non_null_val
  where student_id = 1
  and latest_dt = 1  ;
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KYFmXCsG)

As per performance improvement please share table description and explain plan

Comment: Thank you, Ergest Basha, I learned much from your query and exposed me to new concepts.  It is clean and also fetches data for multiple student ids if the student_id clause is removed.  The only thing missed is the use of DESC in COALESCE.  For performance, my only concern is that this table can have millions of records.  Thank you once again.

Comment: Hey Ergest, sorry for that. I have corrected the sample output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` and `''` do not compare the same way.

```
 WHERE EMAIL != '' 
     AND STUDENT_ID = '1' 
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Since, `NULL` and `''` are *not* the same in MySQL, you need to say

```
 WHERE EMAIL IS NOT NULL
      AND ...
```

Then, you need this

```
INDEX(student_id,     -- first column in this compound index
      date,           -- for the ORDER BY
      contact, email) -- for "covering" of both subqueries
```

With those changes, this may work well:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT  EMAIL
            FROM  TABLE_NAME
            WHERE  EMAIL IS NOT NULL
              AND  STUDENT_ID = t.STUDENT_ID
            ORDER BY  date DESC
            LIMIT  1 
        ) as EMAIL_L , 
        ( SELECT  CONTACT
            FROM  TABLE_NAME
            WHERE  CONTACT IS NOT NULL
              AND  STUDENT_ID = t.STUDENT_ID
            ORDER BY  date DESC
            LIMIT  1 
        ) as CONTACT_L
    FROM  `TABLE_NAME` AS t
    WHERE  STUDENT_ID = '1'
```

(Note that I avoided specifying `'1'` three times.)

(The quotes in `'1'` are unnecessary, but harmless.)